# tengo el siguiente problema con este codigo

Tags: java

Debo ingresar por teclado y luego comprar el dato ingresado con los datos del array, pero no compara y ahora no me permite ingresar por teclado ya que al momento de compilar se salta esa parte.

```
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   boolean pregunta=true;
   
   do{
   switch(procesos){
       case 1:
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese el usuario: ");
        String nombre = sc.nextLine();
        
        
        for(int i=1;i<usuario.length;i++){
             if(nombre.equals(usuario[i])){ 
             System.out.print("Usuario ya existente");
             System.out.println("--------------------");
             pregunta=true;
             }
          }
              try{
              for(int i=1;i<usuario.length;i++){
                 usuario[i]=nombre;
              }
                 System.out.print("Usuario ingresado con exito");
                 System.out.println("--------------------");
              }catch(Exception e){
                  
              }
```

Comment: Esta pregunta tiene erróneamente la etiqueta de JavaScript, pero el código que pasas es Java.

Comment: Gracias! Y como recomendación, intenta sintetizar también el título, es demasiado largo. La explicación detallada debería ir en el cuerpo de la pregunta.

Comment: Si salta una excepción, no hagas un *catch* vacío. Como mínimo, haz un *e.printStackTrace()* para saber A) que ha saltado una excepción, B) en qué línea y C) con qué mensaje. En todo caso, no está claro qué parte es la que "se salta".

Comment: Debías poner el do{} completo.